# Datamapper erases sqlite db when accessed via thin (sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I'm building a small web app using sinatra + datamapper. The app is based on an sqlite database which contains a big number of records in table1 and nothing in table2.

My dir structure is the following:

```
total 32
-rw-r--r--   1 atma  staff  1895 31 Δεκ 21:35 application.rb
drwxr-xr-x   6 atma  staff   204 31 Δεκ 21:10 archive/
-rw-r--r--@  1 atma  staff    82 23 Δεκ 23:59 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x  10 atma  staff   340 31 Δεκ 21:38 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   4 atma  staff   136 27 Δεκ 20:01 public/
drwxr-xr-x   6 atma  staff   204 24 Δεκ 00:00 views/
ls -R lib
database.rb       db_scheme.rb      db_status.yaml    fileutils.rb      greek-dict.txt        greekcase.rb      rankmanager.rb    wodb_el_v0.0.1.db
```

The database is located in `lib/wodb_el_v0.0.1.db`. All these files contain classes.

When I run tests in rankmanager.rb or database.rb by calling the classes by adding lines like:

```
Class TestClass
[code goes here]
end
x = TestClass.new
x.test_class_method
```

When I do that everything runs fine. When I remove the lines to perform the test (where I create the object and run the method) and `require_relative` in my `application.rb`, **it erases the database instead of using it**. The database is handled by the `db_scheme.rb` which is loaded by `database.rb`.

My `db_scheme.rb` is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/4422234).

Any idea why datamapper behaves like that?

ps. I load data to the database by running a manually a method from `database.rb` which creates the database.

Best Regards and thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `db_scheme.rb` you have:

```
version = '0.0.1' # database version
db = 'wodb_el_v' + version + '.db' #db location

DataMapper.setup( :default, "sqlite3:///Users/atma/Dropbox/Programming/Projects/Local/HOWDB/lib/#{db}" )

...

if File.exists?(db)
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
else
    DataMapper.auto_migrate! # erases and creates the database. This needs run before any work is done with the database!
end
```

The line `if File.exists?(db)` checks to see if the file exists *in the current working directory*, i.e. the directory you start your program from. When you start Thin, that directory will be the parent directory, *not* the `lib` directory, so the file won’t be found and `auto_migrate!` will be run, erasing your data.

You should make sure you always deal with the absolute path to your database file:

```
version = '0.0.1' # database version
db = File.expand_path('../wodb_el_v#{version}.db', __FILE__)

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3:///#{db}" )

if File.exists?(db) #db is now the absolute path
  # as before...
```